# Filtering and summing doesn't work in the same query in swift

Tags: swift, realm

when I sum values without **filter** works fine, but when I use the **filter** doesn't work, the **sum** variable is zero. Here's the example code I'm using. Any solution please.

```
let accounts = realm.objects(Account.self)

    var dic : Array<[String : Float]> = []

    for account in accounts {
        print(account.id)

        let sum : Float = realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter("accountId = '\(account.id)'").sum(ofProperty: "value")

        dic.append([account.name : sum])

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try filter in this way, any questions call me back.

```
let sum : Float = realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter("accountId = %@",account.id).sum(ofProperty: "value")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, with that predicate works perfect!.